# apply modulus operator to Scala generic type class member?

Tags: scala, generics

So i have the followig class:

```scala
class MyClass[T] {
    var data: T = _

    def isEven: Boolean = {
        if (this.data % 2 == 0) return true
        false
    }
}
```

Scala isn't allowing me to take modulus here as there is no guarantee that type "T" will be numerical.

So my question is how do i run this?
I want to allow MyClass to have any type of numeric dataTypes like Int, Float, Double etc

Comment: Note this code is very unidiomatic and shows you didn't take the time to properly learn the language but rather went right into typing random code. I would suggest taking the time to follow any proper **Scala** book / course.

Comment: _"Hi can you explain how so?"_ the use of `return`, of `if` without `else`, of `var`, of `null`; and presumably, the `class` itself is also wrong. - _"but I already know Java quiet well"_ congratulations, I also learned Spanish quite well since I child, but that didn't mean I was able to speak English without studying from scratch.

Comment: _"I just wanted to know the concept of T:Numeric"_ that is called [**typeclasses**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) btw, and you didn't need a weird class for all that, just a method: `def isEven[N](n: N)(implicit ev: Numeric[N]): Boolean` - _"your jargon against "if without else" is totally "Kikya""_ no idea what _"Kikya"_ is suppose to mean and I couldn't find anything googling but I would guess it implies that is just my opinion. If so, no, the use of `if` without `else` is not idiomatic in this language for multiple reasons; again, I humbly recommend you to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a type class called `Numeric`, located in package `scala.math`. This class provides some functionalities, which numerics (like Int, Double, ...) must have, for instance, they can be negated, or they must be able to get converted to Int, and many others, [See the docs here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/math/Numeric.html).
So I suggest you do this:

```scala
import scala.math.Numeric

class MyClass[T : Numeric] {
  var data: T = _
  private final val num: Numeric[T] = implicitly

  def isEven: Boolean = num.toDouble(data) % 2 == 0
}
```

Scala has already implemented `Numeric` for some types such as Int, BigInt, Char, BigDecimal, etc,. So if you use one of these standard types, you'll be just fine, but if you plan to use some type that you have defined yourself, consider implementing `Numeric[YourType]`.
Also, try not to use `var`.

Comment: See it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uvNwaQPNQBKAo8Fv6aKCzw)